# Round number to nearest .5 decimal

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I'm looking for an output of

**4.658227848101266 = 4.5**

**4.052117263843648 = 4.0**

the closest I've gotten is

```
rating = (Math.round(rating * 4) / 4).toFixed(1)
```

but with this the number 4.658227848101266 = 4.8???

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
(Math.round(rating * 2) / 2).toFixed(1)
```

Answer (score 25):

It's rather simple, you should multiply that number by 2, then round it and then divide it by 2:

```
var roundHalf = function(n) {
    return (Math.round(n*2)/2).toFixed(1);
};
```

Answer (score 11):

This works for me! (Using the closest possible format to yours)

```
   rating = (Math.round(rating * 2) / 2).toFixed(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

So this answer helped me. Here is a little bit o magic added to it to handle rounding to .5 or integer. Notice that the *2 and /2 is switched to /.5 and *.5 compared to every other answer.

```
/*
* @param {Number} n - pass in any number
* @param {Number} scale - either pass in .5 or 1
*/
var superCoolRound = function(n,scale) {
    return (Math.round(n / scale) * scale).toFixed(1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda late. But for someone who wants to round down to whole number or 0.5, you can try this:

```
function roundDown(number) {
      var decimalPart = number % 1;
      if (decimalPart < 0.5)
         return number - decimalPart;
      else
         return number - decimalPart + 0.5;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this party, but I thought I would throw in a nice answer using a syntax I saw elsewhere, just in case someone comes across this in the future.

```js
const roundDown = decimalNumber => {
  return decimalNumber % 1 >= 0.5 ? +`${~~decimalNumber}.5` : ~~decimalNumber;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `decimalNumber % 1` leaves you with only the decimal places
- The `+` converts the string representation of your constructed number into a float, for consistency
- `~~decimalNumber` drops the decimal places, leaving you with an integer

Answer (score -3):

I assume you want to format the number for output and not truncate the precision. In that case, use a DecimalFormat. For example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
df.format(rating);
```

Comment: My previous answer does not work in JavaScript of course. Sorry if I caused any confusion. (It works in Java, though.)